# Finding mean and variance of t-distribution to solve for constant c

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, t-distribution

Suppose that 5 Random Variable X1, X2,... X5 are independent and each has standard normal distribution. A constant C such that the random variable

$$C\frac{X_{1} + X_{2}}{(X_{3}^2 + X_{4}^2 + X_{5}^2) ^ {\frac{1}{2}}}$$

will have a t-distribution?

I began to solve this by taking the mean and variance of the above random variable(lets call this RT).

Given the following:

$$E(t) = 0$$

and

$$Var(t) = \frac{\vartheta }{\vartheta -2} = 2 $$

Taking the variance of the random distribution RT

$$Var(RT) = C^{2}\frac{(var(X_{1})+ var(X_{2}))}{(var(X_{3}^2)+ var(X_{4}^2+ var(X_{5}^2))^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

which is equal to

$$Var(RT) = C^{2}\frac{1+ 1}{(3+3+3 )^{\frac{1}{2}}}\ as \ Var(X^2)=3\sigma^2 \ and\ Var(X)=1$$

Therefore equating the above to 2 gives

$$C^{2} = 3\ and\ C = 3^{1/2}$$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: A simple way to check if your answer is correct is to resort to one of the definition of t-distributed variables, $T = X / \sqrt{V/\nu}$, where $X$ is a standard normal and $V$ is a chi-squared with $\nu$ degrees of freedom. Does your calculated $C$ enable the fraction to match that? Hint: It should involve a $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Rob thank you for your comment. I will make the changes

Comment: @B.Liu So then instead of equating the variance of RT to 1 it will instead be equated to 2^0.5 and hence the value of C = (3/2)^0.5 ?

Comment: @Rob sorry but could you explain again as to how I should edit my question?

Comment: Do you mean a _standard_ $t$ distribution?

Comment: DBZrasengan16, help is available by clicking on the (?) (upper right) and by visiting this site's meta (extreme upper right *hamburger* icon). --- MathJax help: Short: https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/278 or long: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/510296

Comment: @Rob Thank you for your help. I have edited using your instructions. Is this fine?

Comment: There are at least two fatal flaws in this approach: (1) your manipulations of the variance are incorrect and (2) you cannot hope to determine a distribution from its mean and variance alone.  If you are focused on finding $C$ *assuming* the ratio is proportional to a Student t distribution, then computing a moment will indeed work.  What exactly, then, is the problem you are trying to solve? Finding the distribution, finding $C,$ or learning how to compute with variances?

Comment: @Xi'an The question is as given above. How would the answer change if it is a standard t distribution?

Comment: @whuber Finding C is the problem I am trying to solve

Comment: One convenient approach is to square everything, thereby yielding a multiple of an $F(2,3)$ distribution (by the very definition of such distributions) proportional to $C^2.$ The positive solution for $C$ is the one you want.  This avoids working with variances, for which you are applying erroneous formulas, and reduces it to working with expectations.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment. Is the answer given by B.Liu correct according to you? And also what is the error I made when taking the variance. Asking so that I can correct myself.

Comment: Your formulas appear to rely on assuming the variance operation distributes over division and taking square roots, but neither is the case.   B. Liu's approach is perfectly fine, too, but requires slightly different reasoning to solve for $C.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to find $C$ such that $$C\frac{X_1+X_2}{\left(X_3^2+X_4^2+X_5^2\right)^{1/2}}$$ follow a $t$-distibution. Here is how you should proceed.

**Answer**

As $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independents and standard normal distributed, $X_1+X_2\sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$ and then $U := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X_1+X_2)$ is a standard normal random variable.

As $X_3, X_4$ and $X_5$ have standard normal distribution, $V := X_3^2+X_4^2+X_5^2$ has a $\mathcal{X}^2$ distribution with degree of freedom $\nu=3$.

After all, we know that $\frac{U}{\sqrt{V/\nu}}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X_1+X_2)}{\sqrt{\left(X_3^2+X_4^2+X_5^2\right)/3}} = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{X_1+X_2}{\left(X_3^2+X_4^2+X_5^2\right)^{1/2}}$ follow a $t$-distribution.

So $C = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$

Comment: $U$ is not a standard Normal variable.  I suspect you mean to set $U = (X_1+X_2)/\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: @whuber yes i was thinking the same. I have made the edit. Let me know if it is correct?

Comment: @Whuber, you're right